# Change and remove a part of url with redirect 301 (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I converted a Joomla website to WordPress. Joomla article URLs have `/blog/<RandomNumber>-slug`. For example:

```
example.com/blog/164-postname

example.com/blog/214-anotherpostname
```

I need to remove `/blog/164-postname` from URL so it redirects to `example.com/postname`

Also there are some product category URLs with this format:

```
example.com/category/<RandomNumber>-slug
```

For example:

```
example.com/category/12-catname
```

I want to redirect these urls by changing `category` to `product-category` and removing numbers and `-` character so mentioned URL redirects to `example.com/product-category/catname` with 301 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
# Redirect "/blog/123-postname" to "/postname"
RewriteRule ^blog/\d+-([\w-]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect "/category/123-catname" to "/product-category/catname"
RewriteRule ^(category)/\d+-([\w-]+)$ /product-$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences contain the match from the parenthesised subpatterns in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.